# Backbone.js executing _.each loop with single model

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/template" id="iterator_template">
<table>
<% _.each(value, function(user)  { %>
<tr><td><%= user.name %></td>
<td><%= user.email %></td></tr>
<% }); %>
</tr></table>
</script>

<div id ="iterator_container"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

(function($){
var UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: 'http://localhost/backbone/users',
});

IteratorView = Backbone.View.extend({
     el: '#iterator_container',
     initialize: function(){
     var self = this;
     var userDetails = {id:2};
     self.user = new UserModel(userDetails); 
     self.user.fetch({ 
     success: function (user) { 
        self.render();
    }
    });
    },
    render: function(){
        var template = _.template( $("#iterator_template").html(), {value: this.user}  
    );
        this.$el.html( template );
    },
   });

   var form_view = new IteratorView();

   })(jQuery);
```

If the server returns:

```
   [{"name":"John Hancock","email":"johnhancock@backbone.com"}]  ... 1.
```

there is no output.

If the server returns:

```
   {"name":"John Hancock","email":"johnhancock@backbone.com"}
```

the loop executes twice.

I want the loop to execute once with 1.  How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no need of loop because its passing only one model to template, you should use loop if you pass collection

```
<script type="text/template" id="iterator_template">
    <table>
    <tr><td><%= user.name %></td>
    <td><%= user.email %></td></tr>
    </tr></table>
    </script>
```

backbone expects the response to be array but this value returned from the server

```
 [{"name":"John Hancock","email":"johnhancock@backbone.com"}]
```

is object , hence it is not working

**edit : answer to your comment**

write this parse function in your model

```
parse : function(response){
return response[0];
}
```

this will return the array from the object and set the values to model

now in `success` call back of model add to `collection`

```
mymodel.fetch({
   success : function(){
    mycollction.add(mymodel);
}
})
```

keep the template as it was in the question and now pass this `collection` as `JSON` to template

Comment: Yes, I understand what you are saying.  Problem is that my code sends the JSON back as [].  If I have a collection consisting of a single model then this structure works. Maybe the answer is to get the model and insert it into a collection and then iterate through that.  Not sure how to do that though.

Comment: Why not fetch a `collection` instead of a `model`, if the server returns an array ? Or you can use `parse` to return only the first object of array.

Comment: @user1884367 can you check the answer and comment

Comment: Yes, overriding the default parse method with your code and then adding the model to the collection works perfectly.  Thanks for your help.